# For each element in a 1D numpy array, find the lowest index element from second array such that the value and index both are greater than the first

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have two 1D numpy arrays of length 1 million approx. For each element x in the first array, I want the lowest index element y from the second array such that y > x and arg(y) > arg(x) i.e. index of y > index of x.

Suppose,

arr1 = [3,2,1,0,3,2,3]
arr2 = [0,2,1,2,3,4,6,5]

The outputs are-

values = [4,3,2,3,4,6,5]
indices = [5,4,3,4,5,6,7]

Totally lost. Cannot use broadcasting as the arrays are of length 1 million. I have tried broadcasting to get the element such that y > x but I am not able to figure out how to apply the second condition.

Comment: what if some value `x` does not fit the conditions  y > x and arg(y) > arg(x), like `arr1 = [3,2,1,0,3,2,3] arr2 = [0,2,1,2,3,4,6,3]` - last value `3`, what it should do: skip it or put `np.nan` to the result?

Answer (score 0):

***For relatively small arrays:***

`arr2` can be broadcasted to `arr1` to perform `>` (*greater than*) comparison by values (`arr2 > arr1[:, None]`) and indices (`np.indices(arr2.shape)[0] > np.indices(arr1.shape)[0][:, None]`). 
This involves placing a new axis on `arr1` to make it a column vector, and eventually creates 2 boolean masks.
The intersection of those masks allows to find the first valid indices with [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), which are then used for taking values with [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html).
The whole solution is as follows:

```
indices = (np.argmax((arr2 > arr1[:, None]) 
           & (np.indices(arr2.shape)[0] > np.indices(arr1.shape)[0][:, None]), axis=1))
values = np.take(arr2, indices)
```

---

```
indices
array([5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

values
array([4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5])
```

---

***For millionth arrays:***

I'd suggest using [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html) with `njit` + `parallel` for high performance computation:

```
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def arrange_arrays(a1, a2):
    indices = np.empty_like(a1)
    values = np.empty_like(a1)

    for i in prange(len(a1)):
        for j in prange(i + 1, len(a2)):
            if j > i and a2[j] > a1[i]:
                values[i] = a2[j]
                indices[i] = j
                break

    return (values, indices)


arr1 = np.random.randint(0, 1000_000, 1000_1000)
arr2 = np.random.randint(0, 1000_000, 1000_1000)

values, indices = arrange_arrays(arr1, arr2)
print(values[:30], indices[:30])
```

---

```
[428072 628854 791813 796369 924274 901268 732129 949403 949403 800018
 985390 750386 602616 791772 870306 870306 857630 759459 335358 881248
 881248 985390 985390 773380 940193 987427 987427 987427 386893] [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9  9 10 23 12 13 14 16 16 17 18 20 21 21 23 23 24
 25 31 31 31 29 31]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you step through arr1, you can slice arr2 so that the slice includes only indexes that exceed the index of the current value in arr1.  You can then step along the slice of arr2 until you find a value that exceeds the current value from arr1.  In this case, you only consider items in arr2 that meet both requirements; you perform the minimal number of comparisons; your average maximum number of comparisons (over the values in arr1) is the length of arr1 divided by 2; the total maximum number of comparisons is n*(n-1)/2, where n is the length of arr1; and the expected number of comparisons is half the maximum.

```
arr1 = [3,2,1,0,3,2,3] 
arr2 = [0,2,1,2,3,4,6,5]
arr_val = []
arr_ind = []
for xindx, x in enumerate(arr1):
    for yindx, y in enumerate(arr2[xindx+1:]):
        if (y>x):
            arr_val.append(y)
            arr_ind.append(yindx+xindx+1)
            break
# [4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5], [5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

This code yields the results that you require

[4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

An alternative approach uses .where()

```
import numpy as np
np_arr1 = np.array([3,2,1,0,3,2,3])
np_arr2 = np.array([0,2,1,2,3,4,6,5])
np_arr_val = np.array([])
np_arr_ind = np.array([])
for xindx, x in enumerate(np_arr1):
    yloc = np.where(np_arr2[xindx+1:] > x)[0][0] + xindx+1
    np_arr_val = np.append(np_arr_val, np_arr2[yloc])
    np_arr_ind = np.append(np_arr_ind, yloc)
print(np_arr_ind)
print(np_arr_val)
```

This produces the same results.